# Meaningful analysis of (expected) spikes in data?

Tags: time-series, inference, descriptive-statistics

I'm working on a project that does simulations / measurements where we measure values between [-1, 1] (but we also use absolutes [0, 1] to make life simpler).

It's 'good' when everything is as close as possible to zero.
It's 'bad' when a few measurements (even a single one) is larger than 0.05 and 'critical' when close to 1.

The amount of measurements ranges from 20,000 to more than 1,000,000 per test.

When we make a change we simulate the effects. When plotting/graphing it's possible as a human to easily "see" if the changes made improvements (less 'peaks') or made it worse (more 'peaks'), e.g.:

11 peaks:
[image: graph showing eleven peaks]

improvements which resulted in 4 peaks:
[image: graph showing four peaks]

I never needed to analyse such data mathematically, but I'm struggling to find some mathematical concepts, functions, algorithms or approaches to say anything meaningful about the reduction in peaks. As a human I can "see" the improvement is around ~2.75, but mathematically I tried using a few statistics:

- total area of graph
- mean values
- standard deviation values
- combination of values above, either multiplied or divided by others or the total measurement count

I think the problem is that the amount of data points when peaks occur is very small, but I also can't hardcode the 0.05 and 1 values for filtering peaks out, because it's possible to have a test that's 0.001 everywhere but with peaks that are 0.05 (also bad) - I think normalizing such data would allow me to apply any solutions I get in this post (so increasing all values by a factor one divided by the biggest value).

But in none of the above cases I got any human comprehensible values. I'm wondering what algorithmic approaches would allow me to automate such 'peaks' analysis, and allow a program to "see" the improvement is ~2.75x in the above graphs?

Comment: A starting point is to articulate 'better' in more precise words. There is something bad about the peaks, but is it the number of peaks, the area, the height? This depends on the underlying physical processes. What does 'better' and 'bad' mean?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus mere presence of the peaks is bad, it's hard to specify an exact amount but anything that stands out if unwanted.

Comment: *"it's hard to specify an exact amount"* You do not have to specify an amount, but it would help when you explain the *meaning* of bad and *how* it comes that a spike is bad. If something is bad, what does it matter to you? Are your gonna have different actions based on 4 spikes or 11 spikes?

Comment: To be more exact, this is correlation analysis -- we do "something" (an action), we measure something that's measurable (accessible to attackers), then correlation is calculated [black box] across all measurements regardless of the time the action was taken. To improve security the goal is to reduce the possibility to correlate actions to any measurements, even one spike can leak sensitive information, that's unwanted. It'd be best if there were none spikes at all. I'm trying to quantify improvements mathematically in that regard because manual analysis is really slow and allows human errors.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus as for answering the question "what different actions are we going to take"; if there would be more spikes due to the changes, the changes would be reverted, if less, the changes would be accepted and eventually improved upon to have less spikes.

Answer (score 0):

To get an overall number to compare graph to graph, add up the peak areas. It looks like the width is usually 1, so you would just sum up all of the measured values.

Now repeat, but subtract 0.05 from each value -- and only sum up positive values. This gives you the area above 0.05.

Finally, create a [frequency plot](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/files/2020/03/cumul2.png), but order it in reverse, so 1 is at the left of the x-axis and 0 is at the right. This will give you a good cumulative picture of what the results were. You can, then, if you want, compute % of points in each frequency bucket.